# Efficiency of maximum power transfer

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, thevenin, efficiency

I’ve got this question regarding maximum power transfer. I’m trying to find the efficiency of the circuit by dividing power absorbed over power supplied. I think I found power absorbed (PL) by using KCL to find the Thevenin voltage (40/3) and resistance (3) to find the current going through the load resistance as 20/9. However, I’m stuck on trying to find the power supplied.

[image]

Comment: You need to find the voltage across the current source to determine how much power is being supplied to the circuit. This should be pretty easy if you know the load resistance and load power. Since this is a homework question I'm just giving you a hint.

Answer (score 1):

Maximum power transfer occurs when the load impedance equals the source impedance so you need to find the source impedance and then set the load to that.

You have a current source paralleled with a resistance. That can be looked at as a Norton equivalent for a two terminal circuit. The 4\$\Omega\$ resistor is then in series between that and the output of *Circuit A*.

You want a single impedance so you want to combine the impedance of the Norton equivalent with the 4\$\Omega\$ resistor, you can do that by transforming from a Norton to a Thevenin equivalent. Redrawing the circuit with the 10 A current source and 1\$\Omega\$ resistor replaced with their Thevenin equivalent should make the solution clear. Transforming the Norton source to Thevenin should only involve the current source and parallel resistance, I believe you tried to include the 4\$\Omega\$ resistor in the transformation, which threw your results off (hint: if you have a 4\$\Omega\$ resistor in series with the output of a two terminal circuit it's output impedance can't be less than that.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5ad5h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{I}_0=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2\tag1$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_0&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_0&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

So, we can now solve for the efficiency:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\eta&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{P}_{\text{R}_3}}{\displaystyle\text{P}_\text{i}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{I}_2\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{I}_0\text{V}_1}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\text{I}_0\text{R}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3}\cdot\frac{\text{I}_0\text{R}_1\text{R}_3\displaystyle}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3}}{\displaystyle\text{I}_0\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{I}_0\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_1\text{R}_3}{\displaystyle\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}
\end{split}\tag4
\end{equation}

We can also see that the maximum power is given to \$\text{R}_3\$ when:

$$\frac{\displaystyle\partial\text{P}_{\text{R}_3}}{\displaystyle\partial\text{R}_3}=\frac{\displaystyle\left(\text{I}_0\text{R}_1\right)^2\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2-\text{R}_3\right)}{\displaystyle\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)^3}=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{R}_3=\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\tag5$$

So, for the efficiency we get:

$$\eta=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)}{\displaystyle\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)\right)\left(\text{R}_2+\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)\right)}=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle2}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+2\text{R}_2}\tag6$$

So, in your case we get:

$$\eta=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle2}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle1+2\cdot4}=\frac{1}{18}\approx5.55556\space\text{%}\tag7$$